# How to post photos on Facebook wall from own website - facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I managed to create a facebook app that lets users visit my website and upload their photos directly to my facebook fan page using a user name and a login.

Depending on their username and login - the user can upload their photos to their specific album on my facebook fan page!

Now I was wondering whether the following is possible:

I wish that if every time a user uploads a photo it is displayed on the fan page wall.

Thanks very much xxx :-)

Comment: Its very confusing .
You should mention about the language(java,php,.. etc)..
Otherwise we can't answer the question.

Comment: The language I am using is PHP. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't login using username and password, you need to use Facebook's [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow and APIs to access users' details.

If you want to accept photos directly from users and have them posted to the Page you'll need to get a [Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) for your page and use that to upload the photo